# Remove all products from one category programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

I just want to remove all products from given category,

for that I have tried below code which works absolutely fine , But it takes to much time ,

So I just want some code which works faster than this

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
foreach($productCollection as $product){   
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
         ->removeProduct($categoryId,$product->getId());
}
```

Comment: How can i remove products from selected category, actually the products assigned three categories, i need remove one category?

Comment: @zus in this code `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
            ->removeProduct($categoryId,$productId);`

Comment: My code : <?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct('1','3');
?>:: product id : 1, category id: 3, its not removing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(176);
$category->setPostedProducts(array());
$category->save();
```

Comment: Great answer from  Guineas , Thank you Marius you save my time . I  Will accept answer after 15 min

Comment: Alternative (maybe wrong) assumption: using `unsetPostedProducts()` ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. There is no method `unsetPostedProducts` and it cannot be magically called. if you try with `unsPostedProducts` it will still not work because the category save method takes into account products only if `data['posted_products']` is set. That's why it needs to be an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

Another wayt,you can do instead of run code and run this **two MySql queries** and it will works:

> ```
> delete from catalog_category_product where category_id = [Your_CATEGORY_Id];
>
> delete from catalog_category_product_index where category_id = [Your_CATEGORY_Id];
> ```

Then you  need run **category product indexing from index management**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have created a shell script and I want to this on everyday , So your solution good if I want to do only at once

Comment: How can i remove products assigned to multiple categories, i need to remove those categories not for all,  eg: product A assigned cat1, cat2, cat3 i need to remove cat2. But cat1 and cat3 retain the same products.