# Add products which have a catalog price rule to a specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database, category-products, magento1.9.3

I got 11 different catalog price rules set up in my Magento 1.9.3 store and I've got a script randomly activating one of the price rules every day with a cronjob.

Now I want to add the products which have a catalog price rule activated to a specific category so I will have 'Day deals' which are randomly selected every day.

I'm no expert at all in coding but by googling I came up with this:

To clear the category of products first:

```
    <?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(846);
$category->setPostedProducts(array());
$category->save();


?>
```

And to add the products in the category:

```
    <?php
require 'app/Mage.php';

$category_id = 846;
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product');
$productIdList = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT product_id FROM '.$tableName.''); 


foreach ($productIdList as $productId) {
    $product = $productId['product_id'];

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
            ->assignProduct($category_id,$product);
            }
            ?>
```

Unfortunately, it isn't working. What should I do to make this work?

** FIX UPDATE **

The second script needed

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
```

Comment: Do you have a flat category enabled?

Comment: No I don't, so the code should be working?

Comment: Clear category product code is working?

Comment: Yes, as founded here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149165/63888

Comment: please check by echo $product if it is returning product id or not, I think $productId will return you product id instead of $product, please check by echo

Comment: I'm getting an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Mage_Core_Exception: Mage registry key "original_include_path" already exists in /home/haarde1q/public_html/app/Mage.php:595 Stack trace: #0 /home/haarde1q/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...') #1 /home/haarde1q/public_html/app/Mage.php(31): Mage::register('original_includ...', '/home/haarde1q/...') #2 /home/haarde1q/public_html/dag-aanbieding.php(19): require('/home/haarde1q/...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/haarde1q/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 595

Comment: Have you added such code :  require('/home/haarde1q/...')? Issue is in this line of your code, as per error the one you are trying to include is already included in Mage.php

Comment: No there is only the code I put above, on line 19 is:
 require 'app/Mage.php';

Comment: I found the solution; I put: require_once 'app/Mage.php'; instead. It works now :)

Comment: Yes, use these lines on top in your code when you use file on root

require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Answer (score 0):

If you have a flat category enabled, then please disable it first and run that script again, the code which you have used will not work with flat category enabled. So after running the script enable flat catalog again and then do indexing.

Also You can try below code to assign product to any category by modifying your code:

```
foreach ($productIdList as $productId) {
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);

$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
$categories[] = $category_id;
$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
$product->save();
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the categories where the product is in as well? I want to keep the 'normal' categories too.

Comment: $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
$categories[] = $category_id;

This line of code will keep the existing product categories also.

Comment: I still get the same error as in the other comment section

Comment: Is it working now?